# Recommendations / advice needed for application technology set

Tags: java, google-maps, kml, recommendation-engine, google-earth

I have an idea for a GUI application, however it needs a set of technologies that i do not use frequently (as such i am a bit of a novice here, apologies if this is stupid!).

I want a 3D Earth Model, (like google earth, the actual look to be like the terrain overlay in google maps (I don't care about roads, just height & position)). Like google maps & google earth i will wish to add my custom tracks & locations & boundaries; and move / pan / tilt etc...

I cannot however be continually connected to the internet. So i will need a 1 time download of terrain/geodata before i startup the program. (Can this be done as a single kml dataset ? (Is that even correct?) i guess i would need a 'local map server' instead of an internet connection?)

I will need to use a precompiled language (preferably java) to actually write the program in. (Scripting / Javascript is not acceptable) Can i interface Java & KML using an existing library ?

Is it possible to reproduce the google maps 'map window' with the terrain imaging in 3rd party software ? (Can i pull this from open source somewhere?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you want to do is possible -- however -- let me preface this by saying that it will be a long, difficult journey.

Let's start with the easy thing: you can load your data as KML, it will show up as a layer in Google Earth, and you'll be able to turn it on and off. You'll also be able to turn off default layers (roads, etc) either programmatically or via the GUI.

I would use Google Earth (the web plugin thing) tied to a C# application. You do *not* want to use the old Google Earth COM API. It was deprecated by Google as of GE 6, and was truly a terrible thing to work with. Java could also work, but I prefer C# development. In either case, you can use the language's ability to call into the Google Earth API directly.

Here's a good example (C#). It's GNU/GPL, so it may work as a base for your app:

http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/

Essentially, you load a Google Earth web page in a WebBrowser control, which allows you to manage it directly. Actually interfacing with the web page is the hard part (but still easier than the COM API!) -- hopefully you can use the control library linked above to get a feel for how it works.

As for your internet connectivity issue: yes -- Google Earth (even the web plugin) supports caching. The exact amount of cache that is allowed is ~100 MB. Exactly what goes in the cache is a complete mystery. The 100MB limit won't get you very far -- but you can create larger caches (up to 2GB) using the full Google Earth app. These caches work with the web browser plugin, you just have to copy the database file into the Google Earth application data directory (and rename the file I think -- the plugin appends a 0 or something to the file name.) The process for creating a cache is simple -- fly around the area in question at the altitude you'd like. There are tools to help automate this, such as:

http://bx11.110mb.com/gecacher.htm

Note that caching Google's data isn't exactly what they'd like you to do. So please keep in mind that you'll need to fully review the EULA to make sure you're not violating it...

Good luck! I've been working with GE in a large app for ~3 years; It's definitely a fun thing to work with and can make your application really stand out.

Comment: It is against the TOS of Google Earth/Maps to cache their imagery - see clause 10.1.3(b) - https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Comment: @lifeIsGood Thanks for reminding me - I expect at some point i will have to enter into an enterprise agreement with google as i will also violate some others along the way!

Comment: @debracey Is your app available anywhere ?

Comment: I enquired around a year ago, and at that time there was no allowed way of caching imagery for offline use, even with an enterprise agreement (which start at $10k per year btw). You might be better off looking into http://www.openstreetmap.org/ depending on what your app is about

Comment: @lifeIsGood While it may be against the TOS to cache the imagery, it is 100% possible to cache it for offline use. The tool I linked (albeit painful) works well.

Comment: @lifeIsGood - If i need an official enterprise agreement ill just pass the costs onto the customer who will gladly pay :)

Comment: @debracey - Just because something is possible, doesn't make it legal - especially when the OP is talking about charging a customer to use it. NWS - Paying for an enterprise licence still doesn't give you the right to cache the imagery for offline use. You asked a question, and I am simply pointing out something that might bite you in the ass later, so best to consider it now.

Comment: @lifeIsGood It does if i negotiate it into the agreement and dont cache it offline until i gain that right!

Comment: @NWS - my last reply. You are not listening, you can NOT buy the right to cache offline. Not from Google since they don't own the imagery themselves. You might be able to buy imagery from whomever covers your AOI and then host your own GE server. However there are more issues there and I can't be bothered explaining it all to you.

Comment: There is a google earth portable server you can look into. Then there is no need to cache, you just turn the data server on on whatever computer needs it. No internet connectivity needed.

Comment: @lifeIsGood - I am listening, YOU are not READING! - Please read my post again: "Terrain overlay" NOT THE IMAGES - so YES I CAN if i negotiate it into the agreement !

Comment: @debracey Thanks for the idea about a portable server :)